# Push to github from eclipse - permission denied

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

I need to push a branch to the remote repo from eclipse but I get permission denied when doing that.
If I do this from cmd-line it works.

I have also generated a RSA Key from eclipse and add it to my github account, but the same result,
I obtain **permission denied** when trying to push.

Comment: What push URI do you have configured?

Comment: My github repo. (with .git extension).

Comment: Sure, but which protocol? And did you click on the _Refresh_ button before pushing (because you also use the command line)?

Comment: From cmd line it works (trough https). From Eclipse, EGit it doesn't work. Generated also a ssh key in ecipse and added it to github, still not working.

Comment: A SSH key is not used in HTTPS. Did you clicked the _Refresh_ button in the _Git Staging_ or _Git Repositories_ view? Make sure not to use an outdated EGit version. If you still face this issue in the current version, try changing the _SSH client_ in _Window > Preferences: Team > Git_. Otherwise, show your Git configuration and give an example how to reproduce this error.

Comment: I think the problem is that I have two separate github accounts. One is working, one not, I tried to change email addresses in Git preferences but I am lookning into this, what else to change.

Comment: It doesn't work by only changing my email in gitconfig, I also set usehttppath=true.

Comment: If you have more information, especially about what you were asked for, please add it to your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Follow the steps below to resolve it.

- Configure origin for your git project for github in Eclipse.
- Generate ssh key in Eclipse and add it in your github account.

Now you will still have the issue `permissions denied (publickey)`.

- Go to `~/.ssh/`

Check ssh-agent is running :

```
user@local:~/.ssh$eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

Add the key :

```
user@local:~/.ssh$ssh-add id_rsa
```

Since it was generated by Eclipse you will probably have the following message.

```bash
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0664 for '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

In this case, change permissions of your private key :

```
user@local:~/.ssh$chmod 400 id_rsa
```

And add it again :

```
user@local:~/.ssh$ssh-add id_rsa
```

Now try in Eclipse, should resolve the problem.